# None of + noun without "the"

Tags: definite-article, pronouns

Usually, **none of** goes with a noun preceded by the definite article ***the***

> None of the people I know...

I wonder if it is possible to have ***none of people***, that is, to omit ***the***? Can you come up with such a context?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION

If I mean a nationality or the dwellers of a certain city do I need to use "the"?

None of the Londoners knows it. (or None of Londoners knows it.)
None of the Americans knows it. (or None of Americans knows it.)

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot say "none of people", because when you say "none of X", you are referring to none of some *specific* collection of people (like "the people I know").  Therefore you have to say "**the** people".

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a reference that proves @stangdon's answer right:

> ***None of***
> We use none with of *before **the**, **demonstratives** (this, that), **possessives** (my, your) or **pronouns***:
>
> - None of ***his*** old friends knew what had happened to him. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-none-and-none-of))

So you definitely need ***the*** in your case because ***none of*** will always be followed by a particular group of persons or things.

Comment: So, if you want to talk about unspecified objects (people etc) what other way can be used to convey "none of"?

Comment: You use _**no**_.  _**No people I know**_... But to be honest, the easiest and more common way to say this would be: _**No one I know...**_

Comment: Actually, if you do check the link to Cambridge I gave, you will find this example: _There are no people I recognise here._